# XMLHttpRequest POST call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, aem

```
I'm using XMLHttpRequest POST to send data to a jsp. But the jsp is not invoked. Here is my code.
```

The JS method is called on a button click

```
<form action="">
<div><input type="button" value="POST DATA"
    onclick=test();
/></div></form>
```

JS method to do a http POST -

```
<script>
function test() {
        var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        xmlHttpRequest.open("post",
                "http://localhost:4502/content/myTest.html", true);
        xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            getResult(xmlHttpRequest)
        };
        try {
            xmlHttpRequest.send("username=john");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("error" + e);
        }
    }
    function getResult(xmlHttpRequest) {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                alert("ok");
            } else {
                alert("error" + xmlHttpRequest.status);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

myTest.jsp to write POST request to a text file -

```
  <%
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/test.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
    pw.println(request.getParameter("username"));
    %>
```

myTest.jsp is not getting invoked but i get the OK alert. If i try http get instead of post and append parameters to the uri, it works. I'm using IE8.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)** for making your post?

You would need to include the jQuery library in your page before using it.

Using jQuery will also make your code cross-browser compatible, and the examples on that link are easier to follow.  There are other [jQuery options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you want more control over the request as well.  I highly recommend it--for tasks like this and many others, it will make your life simpler and your coding more enjoyable!

Comment: Yea, I was able to create a fully functional jquery ajax xmlhttprequest, but their api doesn't have their Allow-Control-Access-Origin setup on their server for 'security reasons'.

Comment: If the service you are hitting supports JSONP that will solve this issue.  If it doesn't support it, perhaps it should.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518653/jsonp-cross-origin-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present