# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-OrigCross-Origin Request Blocked yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

I'm using yii2 rest api.
I want to get my information by ajax but I'm getting this error.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://........... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518653/jsonp-cross-origin-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present

Comment: no.It didn't but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this : [Cors filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-filters.html#cors) and [REST Api and CORS filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#cors)

> Cross-origin resource sharing CORS is a mechanism that allows many resources on a Web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain the resource originated from. In particular, JavaScript's AJAX calls can use the XMLHttpRequest mechanism.
>
> The CORS filter should be defined before Authentication / Authorization filters to make sure the CORS headers will always be sent.

```
use yii\filters\Cors;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge([
        [
            'class' => Cors::className(),
        ],
    ], parent::behaviors());
}
```

Comment: thanks.In cores filter I set      `'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],            ]` and now it works.